# tictactoe in python(trouble with printing moves)

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

Okay for starters this is a simple version of tic tac toe, I am in the process of creating an AI designed with difficulties and i have partial code for the AI(randomized) inside my code. Ignore that function but my main difficulty is printing moves on the board correctly. For some reason whenever I choose whether i want to be X or O it auto submits me into X. In addition, if i choose anything other than position A, it will print an X on position A anyways. I would like it if anyone would provide me with the help of telling me where exactly in my coding I went wrong. On a different note, in order to make my game more clear and easy, i would like to print Board and Board 2 side by side after moves are made. This would be to show what moves are available, so if the moves A and B were taken they would not show on Board. If someone could teach me how to do a side by side print that would be great.

```
print "**********************"
print "*THE GAME WILL BEGIN.*"
print "**********************"
import random
indx=0
move_storage=[]
move=["","","","","","","","",""]
#**************************************************
#            This is the original board           *
#**************************************************
def board():
    print "This is the tictactoe board we will be playing on"
    print "         |         |        "
    print "    A    |    B    |    C   "
    print "         |         |        "
    print "------------------------------"
    print "         |         |        "
    print "    D    |    E    |    F   "
    print "         |         |        "
    print "------------------------------"
    print "         |         |        "
    print "    G    |    H    |    I   "
    print "         |         |        "
board()
#****************************************************
#This is the board where the moves will be displayed*
#****************************************************
def board2(move):
    print "  ",move[0],"  |   ",move[1],"     |     ",move[2],"     "
    print "       |          |     "
    print " -----------------------  "
    print "       |          |     "
    print "  ",move[3],"   |    ",move[4],"    |     ",move[5],"     "
    print "       |          |     "
    print " -----------------------  "
    print "       |          |     "
    print "  ",move[6],"   |     ",move[7],"   |    ",move[8],"     "

#This function will store all of the moves inputed.
def movestorage(move_storage, move):
    move_storage= move_storage + [move]
#This function will randomize the computer's move
def computer_move():
    move_random=random.randint(1,9)
    move[move_random]=computer_choice
    movestorage(move_storage, move)
player=raw_input("Would you like to play as x or o-->")
player_order=raw_input("Would you like to go first,y/n?-->")
while indx==0:
    if 'x' or 'X' == player:
        player_choice="X"
        computer_choice="O"
        if 'y' or 'Y' in player_order:
            print 
        elif 'n' or 'N' in player_order:
            print
            print "The computer will go first, press ENTER to see the computers turn"
    elif 'o' or 'O' == player:
        player_choice="O"
        computer_choice="X"
        if 'y' or 'Y' in player_order:
            print
        elif 'n' or 'N' in player_order:
            print
            print "The computer will go first, press ENTER to see the computers turn"
    x=0
    while 2>x:  #This is where the player decides where he wants to go
        choice=raw_input("Choose where you would like to move-->")
        if choice == 'a' or 'A':
            move[0]=player_choice
            movestorage(move_storage, move)
        elif choice == 'b' or 'B':
            move[1]=player_choice
            movestorage(move_storage, move)
        elif choice == 'c' or 'C':
            move[2]=player_choice
            movestorage(move_storage, move)
        elif choice == 'd' or 'D':
            move[3]=player_choice
            movestorage(move_storage, move)
        elif choice == 'e' or 'E':
            move[4]=player_choice
            movestorage(move_storage, move)
        elif choice == 'f' or 'F':
            move[5]=player_choice
            movestorage(move_storage, move)
        elif choice == 'g' or 'G':
            move[6]=player_choice
            movestorage(move_storage, move)
        elif choice == 'h' or 'H':
            move[7]=player_choice
            movestorage(move_storage, move)
        elif choice == 'i' or 'I':
            move[8]=player_choice
            movestorage(move_storage, move)
        board2(move)
```

Also I have some blank print statements for neatness, they are not mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if 'x' or 'X' == player` does *not* mean `player` is either `x` or `X`, it means `if ('x') or ('X' == player)` instead, so test both `'x'` as a boolean, and test `'X' == player` as a boolean and then the whole expression is `True` if the first *or* the second part is `True`.

Since the first is a string of length greater than 0, it'll *always* be `True`, and the second test is never made:

```
>>> bool('x' or 'X' == 'fiddlesticksandflapdoodles')
True
>>> bool('x')
True
>>> bool('X' == 'fiddlesticksandflapdoodles')
False
```

Use:

```
if 'x' == player or 'X' == player:
```

instead, or:

```
if player in ('x', 'X'):
```

or:

```
if player.lower() == 'x':
```

all of which test for the same thing.

This applies to all your `if` statements testing against upper and lowercase letters, such as `'n' or 'N'`, and `'o' or 'O'`.

As for your long list of `if choice` tests; just use a mapping to map letter to number:

```
choices = {letter: number for number, letter in enumerate('abcdefghi')}
```

Now you can use `choices` to map to an index:

```
index = choices.get(choice.lower())
if index is not None:
    move[index] = player_choice
    movestorage(move_storage, move)
```

Comment: I thought i was doing something wrong, thank you ill try that out....okay so now the O or X part is working however I am still having move difficulties, the program insists on printing whatever i pick, in spot A

Comment: This has got to be by far the most common beginners' programming logic error. How do we nip it in the bud?

Comment: I agree, looking at it quickly the logic made sense in my head, but when Martijn Pieters pointed it out, it makes sense now why that does not work.

Comment: Okay i will, but it gives me a syntax error for the colon after letter in the variable choices. I dont know why

Comment: @Alvaro: That's because I was not paying attention and mixing syntaxes; I meant to make it a dict comprehension. You can use `dict((letter, number) for number, letter in enumerate('abcdefghi'))` as well if you are using Python 2.6 or older.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry i forgot to include that i was using Python 2x

Comment: Oh okay sorry, ill just try to look around and find out. Thanks for everything.